# Command-line program to indent PHP files

Tags: php, indentation, auto-indent

I'm looking for a indent application to fix all aspects of PHP code formatting - convert spaces, perform indentation in PHP and HTML code, leave HEREDOC alone, etc.

Please recommend a decent indenter for PHP.

Comment: Note - i want to perform indentation on ALL my PHP files in a folder, not each file individually.

Comment: http://codeassembly.com/A-php-code-beautifier-that-works/  works on a per-file basis, but should be trivial to wrap it so it works per-directory.

Comment: i'm experimenting with "vim -esc "normal gg=G" -c "wq" -e" too.

Comment: Notice: @MarcB 's your link are seems to be evil page. It might be jacked by domain pirates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 2018 answer

Since originally finding solution, I've moved on to use https://styleci.io/. I am not affiliated with them, but I really like the simplicity and it keeps the project nice and tidy. Doesn't cost anything for my open-source project either.

Answer (score 7):

```
find . -name '*.php' -printf "echo -e \"G=gg\n:wq\n\" | vim %p\n" | sh
```

Comment: That is pretty nice, but it is adding a space between the <? and ?> php tags, like < ? and ? > other than that it seems to indent nicely.

Answer (score 3):

I have found few things. First, the best way to mass-edit files is to use bash scripting and vim.

Second, vim indentation is not perfect and is not working always. So I had to rather do "=G" manually then review the source.

Finally, vim's command "retab" in collaboration with tab settings is great if only looking to change white-spaces into tabs.

I'd like to also point towards an awesome podcasts where I learned more about Vim:

- http://vimcasts.org/episodes/show-invisibles/
- http://vimcasts.org/episodes/tabs-and-spaces/
- http://vimcasts.org/episodes/whitespace-preferences-and-filetypes/
- http://vimcasts.org/episodes/tidying-whitespace/

Answer (score 0):

[Squizlabs](http://www.squizlabs.com/) has develop [PHP_CodeSniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer), which tokenizes PHP, JavaScript and CSS files to detect and fix violations of a defined set of coding standards. It have `phpcbf` cli, that ensures your code remains clean and consistent. By their definition it should satisfied your need. Consider read their [wiki](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Customisable-Sniff-Properties), for further step.

Comment: to my knowledge it only detects, but does it also fix them?

Comment: `phpcs` -> detect violations of a defined coding standard. `phpcbf` -> automatically correct coding standard violations.

Answer (score -1):

I'd recomment PHPStorm, its not a command-line per se, but it does allow to specify custom code formatting and apply it to multiple files